# Incorrect height of web-app in Instagram WebView on iOS 10+

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, instagram

Good day, everyone!

I've faced a problem with my web-app.
When it's opened in Instagram webView (from the profile link f.e.), the height of the app is incorrect. 
I have a `position: fixed; height: 100%` html tag, and it's height should be 100%, of view, but it has 100% of Instagram webView container. This container has the height of device screen, but they don't exclude the height of top-bar, that Instagram webView actually has. So, my app's height if more then the view height. It causes scrolling and so on...
Has anybody faced it? 
I've tried to open some web-apps in Instagram webView, but they all have the same issue.

Comment: This problem could be solved with using javascript and dynamically setting the height. But seems that Instagram team has finally fixed that issue.